# Trying to make a Cypher fro CS50 - getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50

please do not answer the overall question, just trying to figure out why I am getting segmentation fault after code successfully compiles.
Thank you in advance.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

if (argc == 2)
{

    for (int j = 0; j <= strlen(argv[1]); j++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[j]))
        {
            printf("...\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar KEY\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Usage: ./caesar KEY\n");
    return 1;
}

string k = argv[1];
//assign command line arg 2 to a string
int key = atoi(k);

string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
//is alphs
int s = strlen(plaintext);



string cypher = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
{
    if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
    {
        cypher[i] = plaintext[i] + key;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}


printf("%i\n", key);
printf("%s\n", plaintext);
printf("%s\n", cypher);


}
```

Not sure what memory is trying to be accessed per the definition of segmentation fault. any tips or tricks would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: `j <= strlen(argv[1])` should be `<`, and `string cypher = NULL;` followed by `cypher[i] = plaintext[i] + key;` is probably the reason for the crash.

Comment: regarding: `string cypher = NULL;`   this statement causes the pointer `cypher` to point to address 0 rather than to some memory that the process can write to.  suggest: `string cypher = malloc(s+1);`  the +1 to allow room for the NUL byte at the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Above code shouldn't even compile. Change to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[1]); j++) //<- not <=
    if (isdigit(argv[1][j])) //<- not argv[j]
printf("...\n");
    else
    ...
```

You can see the following statement is wrong:

```
string cypher = NULL; //-> char* cypher = NULL
cypher[0] = plaintext[0] + key;
cypher[1] = plaintext[1] + key;
```

You must allocate memory for `cypher` before using it, or use whatever function that library provides.

```
char* cypher = malloc(s + 1);
if (!cypher) return;
cypher[s] = '\0';
```

Then call `free(cypher)` when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thank you, my code does what it's supposed to do now. can you or anyone explain what the last chunk of code actually means? I want to understand it fully.

Comment: You want to write to `cypher`, so you have to allocate a certain amount of memory for `cypher`. `cypher` is expected to be the same size as `plaintext`. You get the size of `plaintext` using `strlen` (which you have as `s`) then add +1 (that +1 is for the null terminating character at the end of every c-string). Assign characters to each index in `cypher`. The last index of `cypher` should be 0, that's again the null terminating character `cypher[s] = '\0'; `

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes sense and I can see why its needed. !!